# R: Interactive t.test function

Tags: r, r-markdown

I had to teach my friend how to run a t-test on R (using the `t.test` function) and I just wished that the function was more interactive. Newcomers could run the function easily if the function guides them through the test. I was unable to find such function online so I decided to make one myself. Trying to make an interactive function is a huge challenge for me but it is a fun breather in my graduate school life.

I want my function to be able to run like `myttest(x, y, paired = T)` so that Rmarkdown could produce the output normally. I also want the function to run interactively by typing `myttest()`. Thus I decided to base my function on `t.test.default` and add `readline` in the source code where needed.

I used `getAnywhere(t.test.default)` function to display the source code. And I put the following code right after the first `{` so that R could ask for a vector like `data$GPA`.

```
if (missing(x)) {x <- readline("What is the name of the data set?")}
```

However, I got the following error message when I ran `myttest()` and typed `data$GPA` in the interactive dialogue.

```
Error in myttest() : not enough 'x' observations
In addition: Warning message:
In myttest() : NAs introduced by coercion
```

The data set `data` actually exists in the Global Environment and it has the column `GPA` so I think it is the problem with my coding. Why isn't R reading the observations in the `GPA` column?

(Also, one of my final goals is to make R ask for only a data set. R would read the columns of the data set, display them in the interactive dialogue, and ask `Which variable do you want to use as the DV?`. Then I could type in GPA, for example. I also think if R to asked for the type of t-test at the beginning (e.g. one-sample, two-sample, or paired-sample). Do you think this level of interaction is possible?)